# How to stop expressJS routes from stating "cannot get /somepath" on browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, routes, react-router

I am working on a project with react, and in the front end a route is being created to a unique route, the idea is that all this will be a single page, so i dont want to use express and create a seperate html file to handle the new route. I want to use the same html file that created the route. I wish to use express for other reasons though. I am using sockets and express to handle some stuff relating to the routing.

Anyways how would i make it so that a new route doesn't have to mean a new page? i want this handled all with one index file, and i dont want the page to be refreshed either, cause then it'll loose it's current state.

sorry for my bad english, i do not know how to explain it very well. here is my code incase it helps.

frontend.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import io from "socket.io-client";

var socket = io();

class CreateRoom extends Component {
    state = {
        room: "apple",
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col s10 offset-s1 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3" id="room_create_body">
                            <h3 className="center-align" id="service_title">
                                Create a
                                <b style={{ color: "#ffba14" }}>
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <u>nuke</u>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </b>
                                room!
                            </h3>
                            <Router>
                                <Link to={this.state.room}>
                                    <p className="center-align">
                                        <input
                                            id="create_room"
                                            type="submit"
                                            value="Create"
                                            onClick={this.onRequestRoom}
                                        />
                                    </p>
                                </Link>
                            </Router>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
    onRequestRoom = () => {
        socket.emit("create-room");

        socket.on("new-room", (ID) => {
            this.setState({ room: ID });
        });
    };
}

export default CreateRoom;
```

backend.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

const path = require("path");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const PORT = 60;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/public/", "index.html"));
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {

    console.log("user connected");
    socket.on("create-room", function (data) {

        let randRoomID = crypto.randomBytes(4).toString("hex");
        console.log("Room " + randRoomID + " is being generated...");
        io.to(socket.id).emit("new-room", randRoomID);

    });
});


http.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("server started using port: " + PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Hashrouter instead of Browserrouter.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, but out of curiosity is there a reason you recommend the change?

Comment: Yeah, Express won't try and change the route as well when you use HashRouter. HashRouter will just append `#route` to your URL instead. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md